# Not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, format

I have such code in Python:

```
def send_start(self, player):
    for p in self.players:
        player["socket"].send_cmd('<player id="%s" name="%s" you="%s" avatar="*.png" bank="%s" />'%(self.players.index(p)+1, p['name'], int(player["pid"]==p["pid"]), 0))
    player["socket"].send_cmd('<game playerid="%s" />'%(self.turnnow))
    player["socket"].send_cmd("<start />")
```

And the error is in the title of this post. What's wrong?

Comment: You have two lines where a format string is used, and the error coude be in either one (although they seem right at first glance). Which one of your lines does the traceback show?

Comment: I don't know the line cause this is in server-class error. There is self loggin system.

Comment: no repro. w/o traceback it isn't even possible to see whether it is this particular function causing the error

Comment: Please, can you comment one of the lines and check if the error stays?

Comment: I know I have similar issues when the format argument is a list, but it usually happens when there are multiple %s.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code would fail if `self.turnnow` is an empty tuple:

```
>>> var = ()
>>> print "%s" % (var)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
>>> print "%s" % (var,)
()
```

This is because a parenthesized expression in Python does *not* automatically become a tuple if the tuple would have only one element. `(expr)` is equivalent to `expr`. `(expr, )` is equivalent to a one-element tuple holding `expr` as the first element. So, try adding a comma after `self.turnnow` in the second `print` statement.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Disregard this answer, it cannot be the problem.  Keeping for the comments.

Try if replacing

```
(self.turnnow)
```

with

```
(self.turnnow,)
```

helps (i.e. adding a trailing comma).  The way it is now that's not a tuple and parens are merely decorative.  Might not be the case since you didn't provide line number — have to guess.

Comment: it doesn't have to be a tuple in case of a single argument.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Right, but if `self.turnnow` is itself a tuple, there will be a problem.  To think, though, it will be more likely "extra arguments".